# Coreplot editing plotspace

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I came up with a small problem. Now, I've got a program which plots 
graphs. For that I've set up few functions. 
First when loaded the graph gets initialized with the plotspace 
etc. Then when the user clicks a button, a new plot gets added to the 
graph. But with that I have the necessity to change the 
`plotSpace.xRange` and `plotsPace.yRange`. How can I do so after having 
initialized the graph already? 
Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the plot space ranges at any point, not just on creation of the graph.  Once you do so, the graph should adjust the displayed axis ranges onscreen.  I don't believe you even need to reload the data for a given graph after this.

As an example, the following code should adjust the X range of a plot to be from 0 to 100:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
[plotSpace setXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(100)]];
```

where `graph` is a CPTXYGraph instance, in this case.